# How to query JWT secured API from Session Secured Frontend?

Tags: authentication, keycloak, vert.x

I host two separate Vert.x Applications and secure them with Keycloak. The `Access Token Lifespan` is 1 minute for testing.

- App 1 is a Frontend (hosted static files) secured with an `OAuth2Auth` Session
- App 2 is an API secured with an `JWTAuthHandler`

I can login on the frontend. I can query tokens from the Keycloak endpoint and use the api with them.

I now want my frontend to be able to query the API. App 1 now has an endpoint where the frontend can query the current access token of the authenticated user -> `routingContext.user().principal().getString("access_token")`

With the token, the frontend can query the api correctly for one minute. Afterwards, I expected that I have to call the token endpoint from App 1 again to refresh the token. However, it's still the same. Therefore the calls to App 2 lead to `401`s after a minute.

How can I update my approach so that the authentication works consistently?

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the token? https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-auth-oauth2/java/#_user_object

Comment: @tsegismont thank you very much for your hint! I expected the session to update the token automatically but this was apparently a missunderstanding. When updating the user after expiring everything works. I love building things with vertx and your support with small problems where I get stuck is really great, I really appreciate it. Keep up the good work!